# How can I fix the login error (P2P connect failed) on Skype?

Tags: skype

When i try to login it takes about 2 to 4 minutes and after that it shows an error that says:

> P2P connect failed.

Note that Skype was working with me yesterday.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Type the following in your terminal `rm -rf ~/.Skype`,this will delete all your settings but then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Skype server takes the IP addresses of all logged in users and exchanges them to those wishing to connect. If the Skype program had the ability to either accept an IP address or loads the last used IP address, the Skype server need not be invoked for a simple P2P connection unless a dynamically assigned IP address changes. If the Skype server is down, the new IP address may be manually input when Skype programs the function into the next revision of Skype.

Answer (score 5):

This actually isn't Ubuntu related, they've had [outages all day](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13506_3-20026408-17.html).

Answer (score 4):

It is not a Ubuntu specific issue. Skype got a problem in their network. Now things are retuning to normal. You can find more updates on skype's twitter page: https://twitter.com/skype

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `shared.xml` from `~/.Skype/` and restarting Skype.

Here's a kludge of a script that does it for you. Just copy it into `fix-skype.sh`, run `chmod +x fix-skype.sh` and then `./fix-skype.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash  
if [ -e ~/.Skype/shared.xml ]  
then  
    echo "Stopping Skype"  
    killall -HUP skype  
    echo "Moving shared.xml"  
    mv ~/.Skype/shared.xml ~/.Skype/shared.xml.bk  
    echo "Restarting Skype"  
    skype &  
else  
    echo "Can't find shared.xml - this solution will not work"  
fi
```

If the problem recurs, run the script again.

Answer (score 1):

Found my solution here: http://blog.netflowdevelopments.com/2012/03/10/p2p-connect-failed-error-with-skype/

In short, you should delete the `~/.Skype/shared.xml` file.

Glad I checked there as a ton of other sites just told me to delete the entire skype directory

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.